# Why copy.deepcopy doesn't modify the id of an object?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I don't understand why `copy.deepcopy` does not modify the id of an object:

```
import copy
a = 'hello world'
print a is copy.deepcopy(a)  # => True ???
```

Comment: Choose a mutable object -- not a string or a tuple containing only immutible objects -- if you want that test to be meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simeon's answer is perfectly correct, but I wanted to provide a more general perspective.

The `copy` module is primarily intended for use with *mutable* objects.  The idea is to make a copy of an object so you can modify it without affecting the original.  Since there's no point in making copies of immutable objects, the module declines to do so.  Strings are immutable in Python, so this optimization can never affect real-world code.

Answer (score 5):

Python [interns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) the strings so they're the same object (and thus the same when compared with `is`). This means Python only stores one copy of the same string object (behind the scenes).

The result of `copy.deepcopy(a)` is not truly a new object and as such it isn't meaningful to perform this call on a string object.

Comment: Might be more accurate to say "is not truly a new object _when the original object is immutable_".

Comment: Interning is _not_ the reason behind this, as `deepcopy` does not create a new object for tuples either, and they are not interned.

Answer (score 1):

Look again:

```
import copy
a = ['hello world']
print a is copy.deepcopy(a)  # => False
```

Since the value of an immutible object (such as a string) is incapable of changing without also changing its identity, there's would be no point to creating additional instances. It's only in the case of a mutable object (such as a list) where there's any point to creating a second identity with the same value.

For a thorough introduction to separating the concepts of value, identity and state, I suggest [Rich Hickey's talk on the subject](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey).